# Trying to make bitmap Fade in and Out

Tags: android, animation, surfaceview, fade, sprite

Hi im trying to get my bitmap to fade in and out. The bitmap is being drawn to a canvas
on a surfaceview. I am also using a sprite class to draw sprites to my canvas:

```
public class sprite {

static int x, y;
static int xSpeed, ySpeed;
static int height, width;
static Bitmap b;
static CanvasView canView;
static Paint fadePaint;


public sprite(CanvasView canvasView, Bitmap xSpriteSheet) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    b = xSpriteSheet;
    canView = canvasView;
    fadePaint.setAlpha(100);  //Heres where logcat gives me an error

     // divide by 2 for rows in sprite sheet
    //4 colums
    height = b.getHeight();
    width = b.getWidth();
    x = 0; y = 0;
    xSpeed = 5;
    ySpeed = 0;
}

public static void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Rect src = new Rect(0, 0 , width, height);
    Rect dst = new Rect(x, y, x+width, y+height);
    update();

    canvas.drawBitmap(b, src, dst, fadePaint);
}
private static void update() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    x += xSpeed;
}
```

Heres what my logcat gives me:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-273
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mrsai.xsos.sprite.<init>(sprite.java:25)
at com.mrsai.xsos.Game$CanvasView.run(Game.java:101)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: `fadePaint` hasn't been initialized. You need `fadePaint = new Paint();` before you can call `setAlpha(int);` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you did not initialize the `Paint`.  Change this:

```
static Paint fadePaint;
```

To this:

```
static Paint fadePaint = new Paint();
```

Comment: oh wow lol idk how i missed that. Yep that was indeed the problem thanx